# Linux : How to route to interface based on destination port?

Tags: linux, interface, routes, port, iptables

I have a script that makes a lot of Whois queries. If I use only one interface I will get banned. But I have eth1 and eth1:0 to eth1:13, so 15 ip addresses to rotate these queries.

How can I call that whois command so that I specify which interface it will use for the query?

I've seen [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port) but I cannot add the routing table because my interfaces already have a route used to specify the gateway.

e.g. route add -net x.x.x.32/29 gw x.x.X.33 dev eth1

So my plan is to somehow change the route for destination port 43 only, then make the query, then remove that route, set another, make the other query, etc. A little bit like this:

```
route add -port 43 dev eth1
whois example.com
route del -port 43 dev eth1

route add -port 43 dev eth1:0
whois example.org
route del -port 43 dev eth1:0

route add -port 43 dev eth1:1
whois example.net
route del -port 43 dev eth1:1
...
WARNING: -port does not work indeed.
```

So, what would be the simplest way to achieve that without messing up the rest of the traffic of the server?

Thanks!

Comment: The question you linked to explains how to do it using `iptables`, not `route add`. Have you tried that?

Comment: "If I use only one interface I will get banned". You are assuming that the service operator is not smart enough to cover more cases than that. What you are attempting to do may end up getting your whole domain banned.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I answer my own question.

This is not a solution that works for every thing else than a whois obviously, but it can make the trick for a lot of protocols.

Use CURL to make the query since curl has an Interface option.

Of course you need to have a list of whois servers like [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whois-server-list/whois-server-list/master/whois-server-list.xml).

e.g. in perl:

```
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, "whois.crsnic.net:43");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "1.2.3.4");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "example.com\r\n");
my $curldata = "";
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, \$curldata);
$curl->perform;
print("$curldata\n");
```

Then you can parse $curldata to find the thin whois server and to the same thing on it.